# How to move content from folder to another with php

Tags: php

I have some problem with making a script move picture/files from one folder to another.
I put the code belw
Can somebody help me to see what im doing wrong?
Grateful for any tip that i'll have.

```
  <?PHP
       chdir( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
       include '../../bootstrap.php';

       config( 'website.config' );
       config( 'website.countries' );
       import( 'system.cli' );

       class adeleflytte extends Script {

          Public function Main(){

    // Get array of all source files
    $files = scandir("pictures");
    // Identify directories


    $source = "pictures";
    $destination = "/movedpictures";
    // Cycle through all source files
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
      // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
      if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
        $delete[] = $source.$file;
      }
    }
    // Delete all successfully-copied files
    foreach ($delete as $file) {
      unlink($file);
    }
          }
       }

         CLI::Execute();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to move a file is to use a native function:
http://www.php.net/rename

As a parameters it accepts also full path, so it does move files as you need it.

Comment: i can perhaps try this rename function.

Comment: I want the script to take the content of the folder and move to another folder.

Comment: Then it is exactly the answer you're looking for. Just foreach for all files in folder and rename them to the new location.

The rename in php is similar to mv function in *nix systems - it does both renaming and moving.

Answer (score 1):

`rename` function does this

[rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

```
rename('image1.jpg', 'del/image1.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Outputting what you're trying to copy is useful and would help track down the issue:

```
copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)
```

In this case since source is 'pictures' and $file is, say, 'pic.jpg' you are trying to copy

```
picturespic.jpg
```

You need to add `/` between these.

Additionally your destination `/movedpictures` is in the root directory of the filesystem which is likely not what you intended.

Comment: class adeleflytte extends Script {
        private $source = "/home/produksjon/teste_php/bilder/";
        private $dest = "/home/produksjon/teste_php/moved_to/";
             Public function Main(){

            foreach( glob( $this->source . '*.jpg' ) as $bilder ){
                    
                    rename( $bilder , $this->dest . basename( $bilder ));
                    Util::Debug( $bilder);
                    Util::Debug( $this->dest . basename( $bilder ) );
                    
                    
                }
            }
        }

         CLI::Execute();